# How do I omit observing a node's child in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node called `/posts`

Inside posts, I have a node named "viewers". This has children added to it very frequently.  It can reach up to thousands of children.

I don't want to observe the change. I want to observe everything else in the post node, except for `viewers`.

Comment: [Flatten your data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-flatten) and move the viewers to a different path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to ever observe "viewers" with any siblings then you should probably just take it out of that node. Is there a particular reason you are keeping it there?

Answer (score 3):

From the Firebase documentation on securing your data:

> SECURITY AND FIREBASE RULES WORK FROM THE TOP-DOWN
>
> This is a critical concept of understanding Security and Firebase Rules. **The child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.**

The typical solution is to change your data model so that the "unwanted" parts of the data are in different higher-level node.

```
/posts
  36656553
    title: "How do I omit observing a node's child in Firebase?"
    body: "I have a node called `/posts`..."
/viewers
  36656553
    179736: true
    209103: true
```